# Versioning with Laravel / Eloquent

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a products table that has an serial id, a sku, an is_current flag, and then various attributes about the item.  It also has a unique index on sku where is_current = true to prevent having more than one current record.

What I want to happen is, when you change the model and call save(), a new record is created instead and the existing record is only changed to flip the is_current flag.  So what I think I want is a way to copy the model with replicate(), discard the changes in the old model and just update to flip the current flag false, and then insert the new model.  Something like that, although I might not have thought that though 100%.  Can this be done in as a part of an "updating" event?  Is a trigger a better choice to prevent accidents if some direct table updates occur?

Comment: Check out the [laravel auditing package](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways, One is hooking into the save event on the model. The other is creating a new method on the model, I would probably go the new method route. like `$product->updateCurrent();` which would then do all of the logic.

```
public function updateCurrent($details)
{
    $newProduct = $this->replicate()->fill($details);
    
    $this->update([
        'is_current' => false,
    ]);

    return $newProduct;
}
```

Otherwise the saving event

product model

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'saving' => \App\Events\ProductSaving::class,
];
```

ProductSaving event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ProductSaving
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $product;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param \App\Product $product
     */
    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }
}
```

Now you need a listener

ProductSaving

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\ProductSaving as ProductSavingEvent;

class ProductSaving
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Events\ProductSavingEvent $event
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(ProductSavingEvent $event)
    {
        $product = $event->product->replicate();
        $old_product = Product::find($event->product->id);
        $old_product->update([
            'is_current' => false,
        ]);

        return false; // Prevent model from saving.
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the event version of this out and immediately hit a bug in my seeder because it makes several updates to the same model, which causes history records to be lost.  I am worried about any solution where save() doesn't work exactly as expected for any given Eloquent model, because accidents will happen and lost history is a catastrophic error because it involves money calculations.   I wonder if maybe I should override save() in the model to throw an error if it is called and is_current is false?  That seems like a ham-fisted approach though.

Comment: Is there a way to cause $this to become the new record?

Comment: This is why i said I would set it to its own method, Messing with the functionality everyone is used to and might be called somewhere else in the app is a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed, I ended up breaking the history out into a separate table using a pg trigger because it was the safest way to prevent any accidental deletions of history.  I went ahead and marked this because it did answer my question.  Cheers.